# Highchart areaspline plotband height

Tags: plot, highcharts, height

I want set plotband height inside graph area only for areaspline.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If yes, can you please share? As currently written, I don't see this as being [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You will have to provide A LOT more detail.

Comment: This is not possible with a plot band.  What you can do is add another area series that covers the band that you are trying to highlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a plot band, but you can do it with a second series.

So, given an example data set of:

```
data:[1,2,6,9,8,7,5,6,3,6,5,8,7,4,5,8,9,6,3,2,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,6,5,9,8,9,7,7,4,5,8]
```

You need to know the x and y values of the portion that you want to highlight.

Then you can add a second series that highlights that portion, and format it however you want:

```
{ 
  lineWidth: 0,
  color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
  data: [[14,5],[15,8],[16,9],[17,6]] 
}
```

You can hide it from the legend by adding:

```
showInLegend: false
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/t6r7ywaw/

Output:

[image: screenshot]